# Measuring Activity Load time

Tags: android

I have an Activity which inflates many views in its **onCreate()**. When this activity loads, the approximate time take in 2 seconds. I measured this time using my stop watch.

If I remove the contents from onCreate() then it loads in few milliseconds. So it is clear that, complex layout inflation is taking the time.

Now if, I try to measure the time spent in the onCreate, it comes out to be merely 200 ms.

I added following code in onCreate():

```
@onCreate(){
   long startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
   //other code
   long endTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
   Log.d("SSS", "Time taken:" + (endTime - startTime));
}
```

Now the Time taken comes out to be only 200ms. Not sure, where the other time is spent.

Can anybody spent.

Regards,
SRS

Comment: In measuring/layouting your layout view, is it very complex?

Comment: Yes the layout view is very complex!

Comment: So try to make it simpler

Comment: I can make it simpler. But the question is why I am not getting correct load time?

Comment: Because not everything is done in onCreate method

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Jake Wharton's [Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo) library to measure the method call execution time. Just add `@DebugLog` to your activity methods to find the time consuming method.

```
@DebugLog
public String getName(String first, String last) {
  SystemClock.sleep(15); // Don't ever really do this!
  return first + " " + last;
}
```

Would return:

```
D/Example: ⇢ getName(first="Jake", last="Wharton")
D/Example: ⇠ getName [16ms] = "Jake Wharton"
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 Calendar cm = Calendar.getInstance();
             long seconds=cm.get(Calendar.SECOND);
              //other code
             cm = Calendar.getInstance();
             long secondstop=cm.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

consider looking for minutes too for detailed info

Comment: don't forget to reinitialize the calendar cause ir will use the same time, it happened to me also(getting 0 from calendar)